# Why WEBSITES_PORT and PORT in Microsoft.Web/sites is ignored, as well as, EXPOSE in the dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-rm-template, azure-blueprints

Why `WEBSITES_PORT` and `PORT` in `Microsoft.Web/sites` is ignored, as well as, `EXPOSE` in the `.dockerfile`?

Our docker keeps crashing when the health check fails. There is  no respond to the HTTP pings.

We get messages such as `didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080` as shown below:

[image]

**Explanation**

We are running a function app and a web app, done on Nodejs, on the same Azure App Service plan.

A single resource `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` is created of kind Linux using Basic B2 plan.

Then, two `Microsoft.Web/sites` are  created: One of kind `functionapp,linux` for the function app in  and another of kind `app` for the Nodejs web app.

Our web app is a simple Nodejs using express server which is listening to the port:

```js
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
...
const app = express()
...
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000'
app.set('port', port)
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App started on port ${port}`))
```

**Attempts**

The following is a list of steps we have tried and had failed:

- We increased the plan from Basic B2 to Basic B3
- We used `WEBSITES_PORT` and/or `PORT` in the `Microsoft.Web/sites` for the web app. Also, we had created a `.dockerfile` with `EXPOSE` keyword inside the web app itself.
- We tried applying `WEBSITES_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` set to false
- We changed the end of files from `CR LF` to `LF` in the git repository, applying the change and re-normalizing.
- We set `linuxFxVersion` and/or `nodeVersion`
- In `Microsoft.Web/sites` for the web app,
- We set `http20Enabled` from `true` to `false` and applied different versions of `minTlsVersion`
- We played with `healthCheckPath`, `autoHealEnabled`, `autoHealRules` and `loadBalancing`
- We tried increasing `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT`
- We tried to include the folder `node_modules` to the repository
- We tried to create a `home` directory and even a `startup.sh` file
- We tried increasing `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT`
- We tried adding `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`
- We tried adding a capture for all 404 errors
- We created two `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`. One for the Function App and another for the Web App
- We tried adding `DOCKER_ENABLE_CI` as `true`
- We tried to add the flags used in the App Service (such as `WEBSITES_PORT`) using the `appSettings` property of task `AzureWebApp@1` in our deployment YAML file

We even added an entry point:

```js
app.get('/api/health/', function(req, res){
  res.status(200).send('OK')
})
```

Finally, we spend days searching online and trying everything we encountered and since we are still not solving this issue, we were wondering if someone could spot what are we missing.

In advance, thanks for going over this long explanation and appreciate any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker Albert Linga found out what as the root cause of the problem.

Under `Microsoft.Web/sites`, `properties`, `siteConfig`, there is the property `remoteDebuggingEnabled`. This property must be disabled (`false`). Plus, the `kind` attribute must be changed from `app` to `app,linux`.

Then, in the task `AzureWebApp@1`, we changed the property `runtimeStack` to  `NODE|12-lts` so it matches the property `linuxFxVersion` (`NODE|12-lts`) which is inside `siteConfig`, under `Microsoft.Web/sites`